# Why would you be restricted from using both background-image and background-color?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

So I have looked in many different SO questions and google results but I have not found the exact information I have been looking for.

I have a background-image that I wanted to do a transparent color overlay for. **The common answer is to just use both the background-image and color properties, or even on the same line. But neither of those options work for me.** It simply will NOT allow me to have both. Even using a linear gradient instead of color does not work.

The only thing that I have gotten to work is to use a parent/child div with image/color respectively. Which is confusing.

The parent has the image, but the color overlay is...the child? If there is no opacity on the child's color, then I can't see the image at all.

Can someone please help me understand the relationship and why I can't do both?

```css
.color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  opacity: 50%;
}

.hero {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is really about setting opacity on a particular background property, yet you make almost no mention of that. You should revise to be more clear. Your title question is nonsensical, since you _can_.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set opacity on individual properties--only on elements (and pseudo-elements). It sounds to me like you want a background image, and you also want a background color, and you want the color to be *over* the image and have reduced opacity. CSS doesn't allow that kind of specificity.

You can, however, accomplish what you're after with one markup element. Just create a pseudo-element in your CSS:

```css
.color {
  height: 50vh;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800x200");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.color:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero color"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in principle you can use both. You should try to use in this case z-index.
So, the color class should has a z-index higher than hero.
I think this should do the trick.
So, just add this z-index

```
.color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  opacity: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Cheers,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Your background image has no transparency, and is set to cover the entire element. The background colour has been applied, but it's hidden behind the image.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image
> The background images are drawn on stacking context layers on top of each other. The first layer specified is drawn as if it is closest to the user.
>
> The borders of the element are then drawn on top of them, and **the background-color is drawn beneath them**.

Comment: That being said, would you agree that using a parent/child relationship is the method of choice? If so, that would still leave me questioning their relationship.

Comment: Not really. If you want a colour on top of the image, you can use multiple background images on a single element; you'd just need to use a single-colour "gradient" instead of the `background-color` property. However, it would need to be at least partially transparent to let the image show through.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one element for what you are trying to do.

background-image, background-size, background-position, background-repeat might all be relevant depending on your use case.

You can also put a background-color.

If you use the combined form, background, be aware that settings in that will overwrite some of the other settings.

For demo purposes this CSS spells everything out:

```
background-image: url(your url);
background-size: cover; /* will resize and crop the image as needed to fill the el */
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
background-color: your background color.
```

Note, you cannot use a gradient (linear, radial or conic) as a background-color. These gradients have the personality of an image and can only be used in background-image. You can however have several images in the background-image value, separated by commas and with the first one being 'above' the second and so on.

Comment: I'm aware that they can be combined into the background property separated by commas, however I have stated that method does not work for me, and I don't know why.

Comment: Hi, what is the 'they' here? Could you show us an example you are using which does not work - an exact copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### `background` is shorthand for all background styles

See [CSS: background documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> The background shorthand CSS property sets **all** background style properties at once, such as color, image, origin and size, or repeat method.

You should try [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) for setting the image URL separately.

A similar example would be `margin` and `margin-left`, `margin-right`, `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`. You will override the value for `margin-left` if you set `margin`.

See example below where `.box-3` will lose its background color:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 69px;
  background: #696969 url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27) no-repeat;
}

.box-2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP24h.jpg?s=48&g=1);
  background-color: #969696;
}

.box-3 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP24h.jpg?s=48&g=1) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
```